# Unusual Python Import Error

Tags: python, import, module, importerror

Before you mark this as a duplicate please read the whole problem, it is not the usual sys.path import error.

This is the directory structure of the module I'm trying to import

```
root
|_moduleDir1
| |_ myModule1.py
| |_ __init__.py
|_ moduleDir2
  |_ myModule2.py
  |_ __init__.py
```

I am working with 2 different machines. My script runs fine on one and I get the import error on the other. At first I thought it was just an environment issue, but I think something else is going on. When I run my script which imports myModule1.py with

```
import moduleDir1.myModule1
```

on the failing machine it throws the following import error.

```
ImportError: No module named myModule1
```

The reason I don't believe it is a PATH issue or a sys.path issue is that I have added the root directory to the appropriate environment variables and when I add

```
import moduleDir2.myModule2
```

above the myModule1 import in the script, it doesn't throw an import error so I know root is in sys.path or it would throw an error for them both. Also I don't think it is some issue with init.py because it works fine on the other machine. Both machines are running windows 10.

I'm stumped and I have searched and tested for hours with no luck. All I can find is posts that are issues with init.py or sys.path and those are not the right solutions for my problem. Any suggestions or thoughts on why else I might be getting an import error for one module and not the other when they are under the same parent directory would be appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code that tries to import `myModule1`, and show the complete error message.

Comment: Try just `import moduleDir1` and then `print(moduleDir1.__file__)`.  Is the output what you expect?  If there is another directory called `moduleDir1` earlier on `sys.path`, or a file called `moduleDir1.py`, that will be imported instead, and if that doesn't have a submodule called `myModule1` then you'll get this error.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head! There is another module named the same thing located elsewhere in the system and that is what's being imported. Thanks so much! You've saved me who knows how much time!

Answer (score 0):

One of reason may be the second machine that throws an import error does not have the read permission of directory.Please check the permission of the directory.

Comment: That's a good idea but after double checking the second machine user does have read permission for all directories involved.

Comment: can u do one thing. Just write small code to create the file on the location using python code on second machine .if this file get created then module have to access.